# User enters size of array, numbers in array and searches for numbers in the array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm learning C# by myself by book and I need some help. I want to create a console program where the user enters a number to be the size of an array of float numbers. The program will then prompt the user to search for a (float) number and tell the user if it exists in the array or not.

The problems I have are that it doesn't accept float numbers yet (only integers work so far) and that it will only find the first number entered.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        int size;
        int i;

        size = readNumber("How many numbers do you want to enter: ");
        float[] numbers = new float[size];

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            numbers[i] = readFloat("Enter a number: ");
        Console.WriteLine();


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter any number to check if it exists in the array: ");
        float userInput = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (userInput == numbers[i])
            {
                Console.Write("Congratulations! The number you entered exists in the array.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Sorry. The number you entered does not exist in the array.");
                break;
            }
        }

            Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static float readFloat(string question)
    {
        Console.Write(question);
        string ans = Console.ReadLine();
        float number = float.Parse(ans);
        return number;
    }

    private static int readNumber(string question)          
    {
        Console.Write(question);
        string ans = Console.ReadLine();
        int number = int.Parse(ans);
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: What ide are you using? Because you are new to programming i would strongly suggest you to debug your programm and see where the error occures.

Comment: One pretty obvious bug can be found by considering the if-statements in the loop. Try to reason about the code by imagining some input and try to step through the program all the way. You don't have to go very far (HINT: it's related to scoping and flow control)

Comment: What happens if you enter a float? kai's comment should solve your second problem.

Comment: For the float problem, have you tried entering `2.5` or `2,5` depending on your cultural settings the wrong one will result in `25`

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015. Debug finds no errors - only un-handled exceptions when I enter a float number.

Comment: "For the float problem, have you tried entering 2.5 or 2,5 depending on your cultural settings the wrong one will result in 25" .                                         2,5 works (displays 2,5) but 2.5 results in an unhandled exception

Comment: @TobiasR - An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: There you got your answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problems I have are that it doesn't accept float numbers yet (only
>   integers work so far) and that it will only find the first number
>   entered.

It is not clear what you mean by *doesn't accept float numbers*. If you get any exception when you try to read parse your float value, you *have to* told us an example of your input and your `CurrentCulture`. Other than that, we can not help you for this case.

You said;

> "For the float problem, have you tried entering 2.5 or 2,5 depending
>   on your cultural settings the wrong one will result in 25" . 2,5 works
>   (displays 2,5) but 2.5 results in an unhandled exception.

It is too normal. Since `float.Parse(string)` uses your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) settings *by default*, and looks like your `CurrentCulture` using `,` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx), and that's why you successfully parse your `2,5` to `float` but you get exception for `2.5`.

Since you use `break` for `if` and `else` parts, it will goes out outside of `for` loop after the first iteration.

From $8.9.1 The `break` statement seciton;

> The break statement exits the **nearest** enclosing `switch`, `while`, `do`,
>   `for`, or `foreach` statement.

Since you wanna read all elements, you need to delete these `break` statements.

If you use Visual Studio, you get warning for `i++` part as *unreachable code detected*.

[image]

Also your for loop does not too much sense to me. You print `"Congratulations.."` or `"Sorry.."` strings for *every* item in your array. I would assume you wanna show only one time one of these strings, you can use [`Contains` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) for your array like;

```
if(numbers.Contains(userInput))
{
   Console.Write("Congratulations! The number you entered exists in the array.");
}
else
{
   Console.Write("Sorry. The number you entered does not exist in the array.");
}
```

Comment: I have deleted the break statements but then it prints "Congratulations!..." one time and "Sorry..." three times if I enter four numbers for eaxmple.

Comment: @BadtotheClone Read my last paragraph. Since you iterating for your all elements with `for` loop, it is normal to prints four times. You don't need to do that. Just check it with `if(numbers.Contains(userInput))` and you can print your message if the user input is in your array or not. This is exactly what my last code part does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`float.Parse(ans, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat`);

Good luck

Comment: I've tried that but unfortunately it says that: Convert does not contain a definition for 'ToFloat'

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an `else` statement unless you want to get a further action other than finding the matching float.

In your else statement, `break` is actually doing its job and breaking the statement and exit from the scope.

```
if (userInput == numbers[i])
            {
                Console.Write("Congratulations! The number you entered exists in the array.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Sorry. The number you entered does not exist in the array.");
                //break; REMOVE THIS LINE
            }
```

Then it should work fine!

Other than the logical error, also as @AntiHeadshot mentioned in comments :

> Entering 2.5 or 2,5 depending on your cultural settings the wrong one
>   will result in 25

Comment: I have no idea what you meant.. That is already what he wants!

Comment: You have this array for example 1.1 and 1.3 and 3.6 and 5.2 and your solution would find 5.2 ; then start searching the output will be "Sorry the number you enters dose not exist" for three time and at last Write "congratulation the number exist" okay?

Comment: @nik Yeah, that is why he has an else statement! Otherwise he would just use if statement.